# facing error--[{"errorCode":"INVALID_INPUT","message":"rule parseSingleWhere failed predicate: {c != null}?"}] while running async job

Tags: apex, rest-api

While running the code below, I get the error in response.getBody().After drilling down , i realised that the issue is with the filter condition --where start_datum__c >= :startTime.. Can someone help me what is wrong with startTime?
THe code goes here :-

```
 Andelar__c andelar ;
        datetime maxdate;
        for (Andelar__c record: [select AndelarDate__c from Andelar__c order by AndelarDate__c desc limit 1])
        {andelar=record;}
        system.debug(andelar);
        if(andelar == null)
        {   
            maxdate = date.today()-365*5;
           
        }
        
        else{
            maxdate = [select AndelarDate__c from Andelar__c order by AndelarDate__c desc limit 1].AndelarDate__c;
            system.debug(maxdate);
            }
        String startTime = maxDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'');
        System.debug('startTime:'+startTime);
        
        String content='{"query": "SELECT andelar_vinster__c,Kund__c,andelar_friorder__c,andelar_elektroniskt__c,andelar_validering__c,andelar_returnerade__c,start_datum__c FROM KUND_JACKPOT__b where start_datum__c >= :startTime limit 999999","targetObject": "Andelar__c","targetFieldMap": {"andelar_vinster__c":"andelar_vinster__c","andelar_friorder__c":"andelar_friorder__c","andelar_elektroniskt__c":"andelar_elektroniskt__c","andelar_validering__c":"andelar_validering__c","Kund__c":"AccountExt__c","andelar_returnerade__c":"andelar_returnerade__c","start_datum__c":"AndelarDate__c"}}';
          Http http = new Http();
        String baseUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(baseUrl+'/services/data/v49.0/async-queries');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        request.setBody(content);
        request.setHeader('Authorization' , 'OAuth ' + Userinfo.getSessionId());
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        // Parse the JSON response
        if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                         response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
            System.debug('request: '+ request.toString());
            System.debug('response: '+ response.toString());
             System.debug(response.getBody());
        } 
        else {
            System.debug('request: '+ request.toString());
            System.debug('response: '+ response.toString());
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

> where start_datum__c >= :startTime

You cannot use Apex bind notation when executing a query via the API. The API endpoint has no way to resolve that Apex variable.

You must construct your query to include a literal date or date time value, which it looks like you've already created in the variable `startTime`.